# Find root of NaN occurences in Visual Studio 2017 Debugger

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to find the first occurence of a NaN value in my C-Code. I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 Debugger.

Is there an easy way to do this?
I imagine a condition that checks all the variables in scope and if a NaN occurs breaks at that point. Seems there is no such feature. Anyone has something close to that? I am also open to other debugging solutions (that run with Matlab C-Mex-Files).

Comment: I think you're looking for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/350dyxd0(v=vs.100)

Comment: You can print "NaN" without ever having a single variable with that value: `x = -2.718281; printf("%f\n", log(x));`

Comment: I think you should develop/design your algorithm, including any required checks, such that this cannot occurr.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Designing and developing an algorithm which does not produce NaNs is equivalent to designing and developing an algorithm that has no bugs. It is an unsolved problem. In other words, regardless of theory, human development of complicated software is imperfect, and suggesting somebody design and develop their algorithm not to produce NaNs is as useless as telling people not to write bugs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I think I agree. But then his debugging request has no purpose. Instead, he should design error handling [where NaN could occurr].

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie Really helpful, I mean maybe you are even right. But did that help me or anybody else that will read this post?

Comment: @NikosC. That is the manual solution of what I would like to "automatize".

Answer (score 0):

Reading from [the link posted above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/350dyxd0(v=vs.100)), it seems in Visual Studio you can have at most 4 data breakpoints per solution, and in my opinion they can be pretty cumbersome to set up and maintain.

An alternative, depending on how many "live" variables you have, could be to insert manual checks for `NaN`. Either write a variadic function like:

```
bool isnan_any(int count, ...) {
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, count);
    while (count--) {
        double d = va_arg(argp, double);
        if (isnan(d)) {
            va_end(argp);
            return true;
        }
    }
    va_end(argp);
    return false;
}
```

and pass whatever variables you want to check at the moment, or collect pointers to all your `double`s in an array, and pass that into your `isnan`-check function.